# Writing single JS script for assigning ID's to output in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I am creating a website that has a list of user inputs, however at a certain stage I want users to see a summarized page of all their inputs. If the input was not chosen it should not show as part of the summary (as in the script example below).

Here is my problem: there will be multiple user inputs and to write a JS script to achieve what I had done in an example script below will be lots of work and unfeasible. Is there a way the two JS scripts for the individual ID's can be combined into one as in the script below?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div>
            <label>For the first test</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="clientinfo" id="test1" required>        
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>For the second test</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="clientinfo" id="test2" required>        
        </div>

        <button id="myBtn">Test</button>

        <div style="color:blue;">
            <p id="result1"></p>
        </div>
        <div style="color:red">
            <p id="result2"></p>
        </div>

        <script>
          function getUserName() {
          var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').value;
          var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');
          if (test1.length > 0) {  
          result1.textContent = 'Test1:  ' + test1;
          } else {
            null;
            }
          }
          var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
          myBtn.addEventListener('click', getUserName, false);
        </script>

        <script>
          function getUserName() {
          var test2 = document.getElementById('test2').value;
          var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');
          if (test2.length > 0) {  
          result2.textContent = 'Test2: ' + test2;
          } else {
            null;
            }
          }      
          var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
          myBtn.addEventListener('click', getUserName, false);
        </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

P.s. I would also like to know if a user were to press the test button with an input, remove the input and press the test button again, that the first input would be removed?

Comment: can you use a library? jquery would have lots of shortcuts for you. Or you could use class names, and get all the inputs at once

Comment: I am going to try using class names. I only started using HTML this week and Java is quite new to me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all inputs and loop throw the result and create an dom element which will contain the value of the input

and each created element will be added to lets say a result element

See code snippet

```js
function getUserName() {

  var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  res.innerHTML = "";
  var indx = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    if (inputList[i].value != "") {
      var ele = document.createElement("p");
      ele.innerHTML ="test " + indx + " : " + inputList[i].value
      res.appendChild(ele);
      indx++;
    }
  }

}
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
myBtn.addEventListener('click', getUserName, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>For the first test</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="clientinfo" id="test1" required>
</div>

<div>
  <label>For the second test</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name="clientinfo" id="test2" required>
</div>

<button id="myBtn">Test</button>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: What if I want to add the "Test1: " and "Test2: " before the user input as well?

Comment: @RoelofCoertze you can do that by concatenating the input's value with your desired text, see my update

Comment: One final question, how about if I want to keep the label that corresponds to the input. For example the first input will be printed with "For the first test"? Thanks for your help.